# NFSv3 Asynchronous Write Depends on Block Size?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nfs, wireshark

I am trying to figure out if my NFSv3 deployment is performing SAFE asynchronous writes.  I suspect that it is doing strictly synchronous writes, as I am getting poor performance in general.  I used Wireshark to look at the 'stable' flag in write calls, and look for 'commit' calls.

I noticed that, with especially large block sizes, writes to appear to be performed asynchronously:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/share/zero bs=2097152 count=512
```

[image]
However, smaller block sizes appear to be performed strictly synchronously:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/path/to/share/zero bs=8192 count=655360
```

[image]
What gives?  How does the client decide whether to tell the server to perform writes synchronously or asynchronously?  Is there any way I can get smaller block sizes to be performed asynchronously?

EDIT: Here is the contents of /etc/fstab on the client:

```
server:/path/to/share /path/to/share nfs rw,intr,sync,proto=tcp,vers=3 0 0
```

Comment: Hi Joe,

Please post the contents of /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab so we can see how the NFS share was mounted on the client server.